# Filter result set based on particular column value in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a result set as below, where i have the same product coming from different vendors. I want to identify the set which does not have the same price across all vendors

```
PRODUCT_ID    STORE_ID    PRICE

60             1           10.00
60             2           10.00
60             3           10.00

65             1           9.00
65             2           8.50
65             3           9.00

66             1           21.00
66             2           21.00
66             3           21.00

67             1           16.00
67             2           15.00
67             3           19.00
```

I sql query should return the two sets that doesnt have the same prices for all vendors

```
65             1           9.00
65             2           8.50
65             3           9.00

67             1           16.00
67             2           15.00
67             3           19.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below

```
select * from product_table
where product_id in
(
  select product_id
  from product_table
  group by product_id
  having max(price) = avg(price)
)
```

Comment: group by table name? is this even possible?

Comment: No that's definitely not. It was a typo obviously.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:** One way to do it

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t JOIN 
(
  SELECT product_id
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT price) > 1
) q ON t.product_id = q.product_id
```

Output:

```
+------------+----------+-------+------------+
| PRODUCT_ID | STORE_ID | PRICE | product_id |
+------------+----------+-------+------------+
|         65 |        1 |  9.00 |         65 |
|         65 |        2 |  8.50 |         65 |
|         65 |        3 |  9.00 |         65 |
|         67 |        1 | 16.00 |         67 |
|         67 |        2 | 15.00 |         67 |
|         67 |        3 | 19.00 |         67 |
+------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: one question - does HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 works too in this case?

Comment: @evilone `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` doesn't but `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT price) > 1` **does**. In any case thanks for your input. Good thinking.

Comment: aah, thanks, I thought something like this in my head, but you were faster with answering, so I couldn't try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

My query looks very similar to **peterm**'s query, but I used IN() clause. Looks simpler to read in my opinion. For performance matters there's no difference to use JOIN or IN() :)

```
  SELECT *
      FROM PRODUCTS_VENDORS
     WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN (  SELECT PRODUCT_ID
                              FROM PRODUCTS_VENDORS
                          GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
                            HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT PRICE) > 1);
```